# Flag element in groupby if it is equal to his sucessor in next row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
'value':['pot','pot','jebus','pot','jebus','pot','pot','jebus','jebus']})
```

What I want to do is to identify if an id contains repetitive values but only if a row is followed by another row with the same value. So if I have 'pot' and after that 'pot' again, I want to flag both as true.

Things worth noting, it needs to be based according to the ids. So if I have 'pot' in the last row, and 'pot' in the first row of a different id. I dont want to flag that value.

The values must be followed by one of the same value in the next row, meaning if 'pot','jebus','pot' no flag.

Wanted result:

```
s = {true,true,false,false,false,false,true,true}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Code

```
# compare the current and previous row in value column
# to identify the boundry points where the transition occurs
m = df['value'] != df.groupby('id')['value'].shift()

# Cumsum to assign sequential group numbers to different
# trmsitions and use duplicated to flag the rows
m.cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)
```

#### Result

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Note: Make sure your dataframe is already sorted on `id`

Answer (score 2):

With [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to compare adjacent values in forward/backward direction:

```
s = df.groupby('id').transform(lambda x: (x.eq(x.shift()) | x.eq(x.shift(-1))))
```

---

```
   value
0   True
1   True
2  False
3  False
4  False
5  False
6  False
7   True
8   True
```

Comment: ah great, thank the worst part is when I run in my real life data. It doesnt spot any, which means i did this for nothing. But alas thanks